# Call a private void from the Main void to start my application

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I am not very skilled at this void stuff just yet, so any assistance would be appreciated.

**First:** I am attempting to create a file system watcher, to monitor a directory and if a file is added wait for the file creation to complete, then copy it to another folder. I have pieced together the code below, but I can't figure out how to call the **private void watch**, to start it up.

**Second:** does anyone know if it loops on it own? or do I have to create one for it to continue watching the folder?

```
namespace filewatch
{
class Program
{
    public static string watch_path = "C:\\testerson\\";
    public static string copy_path = "C:\\copyto\\";


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        watch(); <---- how can I call watch from here to start it.
    }

    public void watch()
    {
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = watch_path;
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        watcher.Filter = "*.*";
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        WaitForFile(e.FullPath + e.Name);
        System.IO.File.Copy(e.FullPath, copy_path + e.Name);
    }

    public static bool IsFileReady(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            using (FileStream inputStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
                return inputStream.Length > 0;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void WaitForFile(string filename)
    {
        while (!IsFileReady(filename)) { }
    }

}
```

}

*-* Edit:

I have changed the private voids to public static, and now no errors arise, but the console app does not stay running. it just starts and stops now. so it's not monitoring the folder.

Comment: The FSW loops for you.  Your while loop is probably blocking your code.  I don't see where you call "watch" that creates your FSW.

Comment: yeah, calling watch is what I need help with.

Comment: that'll have to be `static` as well.

Comment: You do not understand what the difference is between static and instance methods.  You'll need to learn that in order to be successful at programming in C#.

Comment: You also seem to be confused about the meaning of "void".  "Void" simply means that a method does not return a value when it completes. There's nothing particularly special about void methods except that they do not produce a value when you call them, and therefore you cannot put a call to a void method into any position which is expecting a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make the watch() method static and simply call it from the Main method.

Comment: can't make it static or the (onchanged) call doesn't work

Comment: Just also make `OnChanged` static

Answer (score -1):

I assume that the program starts by running the staic void main string args. If you change private void watch() to public void watch then you should be able to call that constructor / method from the main class.

Comment: I edited my question, I am unsure of how to call that FW void

Comment: well don't vote my answer down if your question is inaccurate.